# Adicionar referencia a um contato numa EditText

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde preciso de um formulário no qual é possível se colocar um Contato. Como posso fazer para adicionar uma referencia a um contato da agenda? Isso é possível?

Minha ideia era algo como: usuário toca no `EditText` do contato, aparece uma janela na qual ele pode selecionar um contato. Na `EditText` fica o nome do contato, mas ao se tocar novamente nela (quando o contato já foi selecionado), abre-se os dados do contato (pode ser numa janela popup ou numa nova `Activity`).

Comment: Queres um contacto da lista de contactos do Android certo?

Comment: Exato. Quero que eu consiga referenciar ele dentro de um item da tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a implementação de um click curto para selecionar o contato e o click longo para abrir os dados do contato.

**Botão**

```
Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botao);
```

Implementação **Click Curto** no botão dentro da Activity

```
botao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Sua Implementação aqui
    }
});
```

Implementação **Click Longo** no botão dentro da Activity

```
botao.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Sua implementação aqui como por exemplo chamar uma nova Activity:
        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, NovaActivity.class);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Note que **onClick()** retorna void e o **onLongClick()** retorna um boolean, sendo assim, retornando **true** no **onLongClick()** ele descarta o **onClick** quando o clique longo for disparado, caso contrário, os ambos eventos irão acontecer.

Comment: ah? Acho que não é nada disto que o autor quer.

Comment: Na verdade isso ajuda. Eu queria mesmo saber quais APIs eu posso usar para atrelar o contato à EditText, mas esse código que ele postou pode ajudar em outros lugares do projeto.

Comment: @JorgeB. Achei um pouco confuso a pergunta dele mas foi o que eu entendi e como ainda não tenho permissão para comentar na pergunta dele, tenho esperança que isso ajude dentro da minha interpretação. Considera que está confusa a pergunta? :)

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk Basta você mudar o botão para o EditText já que todos são view. Só é um pouco confuso em termos de UI esse comportamento visual para o tipo de ação que você deseja.

Comment: Na verdade essa é apenas a ideia que eu tenho, não sei se vou realmente implementar desse jeito. O problema maior é que não sei como implementar tal ideia.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk Bem, isso não é uma agenda de contatos? O ideal é que houvesse uma tela com uma lista de contatos e ao clicar em um item da lista ou seja um contato, aí sim, abriria uma nova activity para visualização dos dados deste contato e aí você poderia ter as opções de Editar ou Deletar, ao editar os EditText ficariam habilitados para a edição. O que acha?

Comment: Não seria uma agenda, apenas preciso associar um contato ao EditText. Não preciso de opções pra editar ou deletar o mesmo, apenas pra visualizar seus dados.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk O que você exatamente chama de associar?

Comment: Por exemplo: quando o usuário seleciona um contato, o edittext mostra o nome dele e quando o usuário toca de novo, abre a pagina do contato